# Cakephp installation

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdo

I have installed cakephp 2.7.5 on xampp but when I run my application I get an error message >CakePHP is NOT able to connect to the database.

Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.< I suspect that my mysql server is not properly configured and I have particular concerns over the PDO and pdo_mysql settings in the php.ini file. How do I enable them? (I am totally lost here)Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why use cakephp 2 and not the new version 3? Cakephp 2 was very bad since it didnt use objects but ugly arrays. Move to cake 3 is MUCH better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention configuring the connection, so your problem is most probably that of a missing initial [database configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#cakephp-database-configuration).

You will obviously need to create a database (and maybe a user with sufficient permissions in that DB) before you setup the configuration. Don't mess with PDO configuration in `php.ini`, it should run out of the box with XAMPP.

Comment: I checked my database configuration and corrected the mis-configured credentials. Problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: Great! You can also mark the answer as accepted for future reference of anyone with the same problem.

Comment: Hover over the left side of the answer and a checkmark will appear. Click on it to make the [answer accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Rename file name from **database.php.default** to **database.php** .Create a database in mysql. Open the file and change your mysql **login**,**password** and **database** from default variable.Then run your application.

```
public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'user',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'database_name',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
```